# Ubuntu 20.04 System Menu shutdown buttons turn into Dropdown

Tags: gnome, themes, 20.04, menu, menu-bar

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop, previously using 19.04.

I've noticed that previously, there are buttons on the system menu for settings, logout and turn off:

[image: Previous System menu]

Now, it shows an dropdown:

[image: New System menu]

I want to know if it's possible to change it back to the buttons. I have Gnome Tweak tools and tried other gnome themes.